# Android Studio - Gradlew Projects not showing

Tags: java, android-studio

i want to update my java Version. So i googled it and found some solutions.
All solutions says: Go to android studio > settings > Build, Execution, Development > Build Tools > Gradle and change the gradle version there.
But the "gradlew project"-section is missing

[image]

Does anybody know why and what is the solution for this? It should be looks like: https://youtu.be/w1xsfg-fj_s?si=rNADkUhPQ4wnC3nd&t=35